# Suggestions with Aucomplete material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

please I am using the Autocomplete component of material-ui to get the suggestions based on the data entered in a TextField as shown in my code below. I would like to get the list of suggestions that are returned by the component based on the text entered

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export default function ComboBox() {
 const onTagsChange = (event, values) => {
        console.log(values);
}
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      onChange={onTagsChange}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: How does the top100Films look like? The Autocomplete should be working out of the box with suggestions

Comment: I want to get the suggestions that are returned by autocomplete based on the value of the textField